# Joomla 1.7: Order of modules on frontpage

Tags: joomla, module, frontpage, joomla1.7

I would like to configure my frontpage (default page). In Menu Manager I set Menu Item Type to "Featured articles". It's great. I have featured articles on my homepage. Now I want to show my special module only on my homepage. So I add new module in module manager and assign it to homepage. Yes, module is added. And this is problem. Module is added before Featured Articles.

I would like to change order of Featured Articles (Content Component) and Modules. Is it possible?

I think I can't change it in Joomla Back-end.

Thank you very much for reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, it's my mistake.

In my main template file index.php I have bad order of jos:include tags.

```
<jdoc:include type="component" />
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="left" style="mfPanel" headerLevel="2" />
```

First it must be component and then tag for modules.